# android.app.ActivityThread is missing in current sdk

Tags: android

I found some examples in the web which use `android.app.ActivityThread` but I can't find it in my android sdk installation (2.1 and 2.2), and neither on the [android sdk webpage](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html).

Was the `ActivityThread` removed from the current sdk? If so, is there an alternative?

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ActivityThread` is a class in the Android firmware, but it has not been part of the Android SDK since 1.0, AFAICT. Whatever examples you are either much too old or are designed for people modifying the firmware.